# mysql giving out 6 from 9 values wrong

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using a query like this one

```
$escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['submenu']);

$result = $db->select('SELECT pagename,metakeywords,metadescription,title1,title2,title3,article1,article2,article3 FROM sub_menu WHERE id='.$escaped.'');
```

and work with the values in metatags etc. like this

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $result[0]['metadescription']; ?>" />
```

But for the values title1,title2,title3,article1,article2 and article3, I alway get the same results, even if im in a different row, I get the result from a total different row, and always the same result but all other values are changing to the new requested ones.

Very weird to me, someone a clue what the issue could be ?

Comment: Try echoing the query before `$db->select()` and make sure it's correct.

Comment: Show the loop rather than how you obtain the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked with print_r($result)  all was good. Then is pasted every time print_r one template father ... and saw that one template was overwriting $result with another query so article1 etc didn't exist anymore. So php used the last value know as $result[0]['article1'] etc... MY BAD :D

Comment: Considering that this won't help future visitors, please remove the question :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is in your data, not your query. Go to the database directly, and run the query. Are the results consistent with what you're seeing on your PHP page?

I would also speculate that there are some issues with database normalization, which could be causing issues with your INSERT/UPDATE script (which I assume is elsewhere), which in turn are the cause of your database abnormalities.

I regularly see similar issues in my students' projects.